# Snowflake - copy column headers for empty row

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am using `copy into` command to store the query results from snowflake into a file in s3 bucket. It works as expected but when the query returns no data I still want to save the column names in the same file so that I can display the empty row with column names in UI. I have specified `header=true` in the command but it doesn't work when the query returns no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html#usage-notes):

> If the source table contains 0 rows, then the COPY operation does not
>   unload an empty data file; not even a file containing the table column
>   headings.

And there doesn't seem to be a way to change this behavior.

However, before writing the table to S3, you could write the headers (as data) by querying the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns.html).  Then write your table as usual (with OVERWRITE=TRUE) -- and if no rows are written, the header file will remain.

---

UPDATE

Here's an how to generate a header:

```
select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by ordinal_position)
from MY_DB.information_schema.columns 
where table_schema='MY_SCHEMA' and table_name='MY_TABLE';
```

You can then write it as data to a CSV file like this:

```
copy into @my_stage/my_table  (
    select listagg(column_name,',') 
        within group (order by ordinal_position)
    from MY_DB.information_schema.columns 
    where table_schema='MY_SCHEMA' and table_name='MY_TABLE';
)
file_format = (type=csv compression=none field_delimiter=none)
header=false;
```

Comment: what is the table name to get header in information schema dbname.information_schema.columns ?

Comment: You can construct the header like this: `select listagg(column_name,',') within group (order by ordinal_position) header from MY_DB.information_schema.columns where table_schema='MY_SCHEMA' and table_name='MY_TABLE' ;`